# Limited VS2012 SQL Syntax Highlighting

Tags: visual-studio-2012, syntax-highlighting, database-project, sql-server-2012-datatools

I have two instances of VS2012 Premium (11.0.51106.01 Update 1) on different machines (both Win8, 64bit). Both have SQL Server Data Tools installed. In both I'm working on a same SQL Server Database Project.

But one instance have limited SQL syntax highlighting options (see screenshot).

My question is how can I get the full set of highlighting options?

[image]

Comment: For other searching on this topic, Kent resolved it by running [DEVENV /SETUP](http://blog.sqlconcepts.co.nz/2013/04/ssdt-syntax-highlighting-disappeared.html) from a Visual Studio Command Prompt in administrator mode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I noticed that the problem is solved some time after installing SQL Server 2012 instance on the machine with limited syntax highlighting options.